# How to prevent copy-directory from choking on Unix socket files?

Tags: files, advice, nadvice, socket

I need to copy a directory tree that holds Unix socket files somewhere inside.  As Unix sockets cannot be copied, when I use `copy-directory`, the `copy-file` function used by `copy-directory` throws an error because it cannot copy the Unix socket file.

In an attempt to resolve that problem I wrote a advice for `copy-file`, called `copy-only-file` that copies only files, and skip Unix sockets:

```lisp
(defun copy-only-file (file newname
                            &optional
                            ok-if-already-exists
                            keep-time
                            preserve-uid-gid
                            preserve-permissions)
  "Copy files but not Unix sockets."
  (unless (unix-socket-p file)
    (copy-file file newname ok-if-already-exists keep-time
                        preserve-uid-gid preserve-permissions)))
```

Then later, inside another function, the code sets up the advice temporarily  to copy the directory tree:

```lisp
          ;; inside some function...
          (advice-add 'copy-file :override #'copy-only-file)
          (copy-directory (directory-file-name source-dirpath)
                          (directory-file-name destination-dirpath))
          (advice-remove 'copy-file #'copy-only-file)
```

This being a recursive call, running the code causes too many recursions and the code eventually fails with the error **(error Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’)**

I thought of using a `:before` advice to filter out files that would be Unix socket files, but then is it possible to *not* call the function being advised when some criteria is met?  Or would I have to pass the same file to the FILE and NEWFILE argument of `copy-file` so that no copy is done because OK-IF-ALREADY-EXISTS would be nil?

I have also thought about re-defining the function using defalias to keep access to the original `copy-file`:

```lisp
(defalias 'original-copy-file #'copy-file)

(defun copy-file (file newname
                       &optional
                       ok-if-already-exists
                       keep-time
                       preserve-uid-gid
                       preserve-permissions)
  "Copy files but not Unix sockets."
  (unless (socket-p file)
    (original-copy-file file newname ok-if-already-exists keep-time preserve-uid-gid preserve-permissions)))
```

That seems to work, but is it guaranteed to always work?  It feels like a kludge to me.  And I'm not clear on how I would restore the original `copy-file`.

What is the proper way to handle this type of scenario?

Comment: You can add and remove `:override` advice to clobber a function definition and subsequently restore it.  There are other options, but that's the nicest method IMO, as it's both easy and visible.

Comment: I would `M-x report-emacs-bug` if I were you.  It seems reasonable to provide users with a way to handle the presence of sockets and/or other similar things.

Comment: @phils I submitted this report: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=49644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:override` replaces the advised function with your own function, so when your function tries to call the original it is actually calling itself. I recommend using `:around` advice instead.

```
(defun copy-only-file (original-copy-file file &rest args)
  "Copy files but not Unix sockets."
  (unless (unix-socket-p file)
    (apply original-copy-file
           file
           args)))
```

Then to add the advice run `(advice-add 'copy-file :around #'copy-only-file)`

See [chapter 13.11.3 Ways to compose advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-Combinators.html) in the Elisp manual for all the different ways to compose advice.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct on both accounts!   I should have read the manual a little bit more :-)